# Hibernate ManyToOne vs OneToOne

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, many-to-one

I can't see any difference in the schema of a Many-To-One relationship vs a OneToOne relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Address address;
```

vs

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Address address;
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

They look exactly the same on schema but there is difference on Hibernate Layer.

If you try something like that:

```
Address address = new Address();
Order order1 = new Order();
order1.setAddress(address);
Order order2 = new Order();
order2.setAddress(address);
save();
```

Everything will be OK. But, after save if you try get Order:

```
@OneToOne case:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1

@ManyToOne case:
SUCCESS
```

Of course, your Address class should looks different in both cases.

Comment: So I should be fine to switch between the two mappings?

Comment: What do you mean by "switch between the two mappings"? If you have existing schema of database and you decide to change mapping annotation in your application you can do it without changing the schema (from @OneToOne to @ManyToOne). In other way you can also do it, but you can have problem with data.

Comment: For anybody reading paulek's post in the future: Your entitites have to be _just so_ to get that error. If you have unidirectional relations only, that error will not pop up. If you have bidirectional relations, only a select on adresses with join fetching the orders will generate that error.

Comment: Why isn't the exception actually generated while `save()` in the OneToOne case?

Comment: I tried save as `session.save(order1)` follwed by `session.save(order2)` and get an exception ` org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value `

Comment: Also can you tell which object calls `save();` here.

Answer (score 10):

There should normally be a unique constraint on the `address_id` join column in the case of a OneToOne association, to guarantee that only one Order can have a given address.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case

Comment: At least with MySQL it creates the foreign key with an index of "Unique" type.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: The schema might look the same at first glance, but the OneToOne may have an additional `UNIQUE INDEX` constraint. This guarantees the **One**ToOne association.

This is nicely illustrated by the [Doctrine ORM documentation of Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) (I don't think it's specific to Hibernate).

An example:

#### ManyToOne:

Consider the tables `User` and `Address` while the column `User.address_id` has a ManyToOne association to the `Address.id` column. This would be the SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    address_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Address (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE User ADD FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES Address(id);
```

#### OneToOne:

Now, consider the tables `Product` and `Shipment`, while the column `Product.shipment_id` has a OneToOne (unidirectional) association to the `Shipment.id` column. This would be the SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    shipment_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_6FBC94267FE4B2B (shipment_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Shipment (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Product ADD FOREIGN KEY (shipment_id) REFERENCES Shipment(id);
```

The only difference is the `UNIQUE INDEX` directive which dictates there must not be a `shipment.id` occuring twice in the `Product` table. This guarantees the **One**ToOne association.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates both sides of the relationship are best served by having the same primary key. It [makes more sense](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) this way since both sides are associated one and only one order in the case of the `@OneToOne` relationship.