# Entity Mapping : [OneToOne] vs [ ManyToOne + Unique Constraints]

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, jpa-2.0

I was answering a SO question about entity mappings, and there was two possible ways to do the mapping :  either with `OneToOne` or (`ManyToOne` + a `UniquesConstraint`).I have been always avoiding the use of  `OneToOne` relationship, I always choose to do it with `ManyToOne` and add some unique constraints for both scenarios Unidirectional and bidirectional, I had no problem with that.

I was just wondering what it the best practice ?

I read some Q/A in so and I am aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460469/hibernate-manytoone-vs-onetoone) but it doesn't answer my question.

Thank you .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452987/hibernate-why-use-many-to-one-to-represent-a-one-to-one is a better discussion of the subject than the post you referenced.

Comment: @Tim thanks, i didn't see that before :)