# one-to-one vs many-to-one (unidirectional)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, many-to-one

An employer has several employees, so employees have (many-to-one) relations with their employer. Provided that we ignore reverse relation (one-to-many)from employer to the employee, then from the employee perspective, this can be represented as a one-to-one relation !?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance it might appear so - you won't get any errors when using a `@OneToOne` relation when it's in fact a `@ManyToOne` and **in most cases** hibernate won't behave any differently since as far as the owning entity (the employee in your example) is concerned it only cares about itself and the non-owning entity (the employer) and doesn't need to know about its siblings (the other employees) BUT `@OneToOne` has additional properties that `@ManyToOne` doesn't since it ASSUMES (seeing as it's a one-to-one) that it has a direct relationship with the other side of the relation:

`@OneToOne` has an `orphanRemoval` property which allows you to delete the other side of the relation (employer) if the owning entity (employee) is deleted - this is not available with `@ManyToOne`

There are also more direct differences in the Hibernate layer, where if you reference the SAME non-owning entity (employee) from different owning entities (employer) within the same transaction you will get an exception when using `@OneToOne` with a relationship that should be `@ManyToOne` - see this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463748/3368558