# Conditional entity creation in JPA OneToOne

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My `Employee`s need to have a role, which later could be extended with other attributes. Because of that, I want to keep them as separate entities.

In the `Employee` class, I am referencing a role like this:

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private EmployeeRole role;
```

while the `EmployeeRole` class has only a numeric `id` attribute and a description as a `String`.

### Goal

Whenever I create an entity of type `Employee`, I want to specify only the `description` of a role, not its `id`. If the role with such `description` already exists, its `id` is what is used as the `role_id` foreign key on the `Employee` relation.

Otherwise, a new role is created.

### Current behavior

New `EmployeeRole` is created for each `Employee`. If I set the `description` to be unique:

```java
@Column(unique = true)
private String description;
```

an `Employee` is not created if a role with the specified description already exists.

### Solution?

A possible solution is to check whether an `EmployeeRole` with this description already exists, create it if it doesn't, and in both cases utilize its `id` to map a new `Employee` to it.

I honestly do not know how to do that in class declaration. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: if you use a `@OneToOne` each `Employee` needs to have a different `EmployeeRole` (read id) reference: [manytoone-vs-onetoone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460469/hibernate-manytoone-vs-onetoone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is not what you are looking for, but you could query EmployeeRole by the description and reuse the entity for your employee if it exist or create a new one if not. If you use JpaRepository you could write a method in it like this in the interface to create the query by desecription column:

```
EmployeeRole findFirstByDescription(String description);
```

Technically you could just name the method:

```
EmployeeRole findByDescription(String description);
```

But then it will not work if you for some reason would accidentally create multiple EmployeeRoles with the same description so by using "findFirst.." you eliminate that just in case.